# How to evaluate and take function value lazy in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, methods, functional-programming

What I'm trying to achieve in my personal project is an 'evaluator function', that should elect a valid strategy, without invoking that twice.
Currently, my code is:

```
fun electStrategy() = listOf({ attemptStrategyA(x) }, { attemptStrategyB(x) })
                      .find{ it.invoke() == true } ?.invoke()

// where `attemptStrategyA(x)` and `attemptStrategyB(x)` return `T`
```

As you can see from the above, I need to first evaluate the strategies in a lazy fashion and then, when the predicate condition is met, I would like to get elected strategy value.

How can I do the above without having to evaluate such strategy twice and more elegantly?

Comment: Well you don't have to evaluate it a second time, since you know the result will be `true` (otherwise `find` wouldn't find it). Your comment is probably wrong if you're saying both functions returns `T`, unless `T` is always `Boolean`. Or maybe the lambda inside `find` doesn't compile

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want to return? The name `electStrategy` suggests that a strategy will be returned (so one of the functions), but the implementation suggests that you want to return the result of the invocation of the matching strategy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your example has a problem with its predicate. But assuming `predicate()` is a function that returns true or false on a result of a strategy invocation, you could write it this way:

```kotlin
fun electStrategy() = sequenceOf({ attemptStrategyA(x) }, { attemptStrategyB(x) })
    .map { it.invoke() }
    .firstOrNull { predicate(it) }
```

Using `sequenceOf` instead of `listOf` makes the `.map` operation lazy, which means the predicate will be evaluated on the result of a strategy before the next strategy is attempted.